# Teechart control ocx not working with window 8

Tags: activex, teechart

Actually we have integrated Teechart in our application and it works fine on windows 7 64 bit.

But now we moved to windowss 8 where our application 32 bit works fine with Teechart but 64 bit gives access violation error.

we taught it might be our issue so we build samople application seriesTxt source and tried to execute we found that the Teeeditor is disable and in out code we used it to set legend size that where it crashes.

Can you please execute the sample code in the Example by building in 64 bit and check on wwindows 8 (64 bit) whether it works fine.

Also we found out the issue might be because of casting some variable in DWORD which work in windows 7 but windows 8 required the type casting to be DWORD64 may be some where in your code this can be the issue.

Thanks
Akshay

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you registered the 64bit version of the ocx shipped with the TeeChart installation?

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the problem. Is it related? If not, please ask it in a different/new question.

Answer (score 1):

Note we changed the CLSIDs of the components on TeeChart ActiveX v2014.0.0.2.
However, I'm afraid the demo in the "Examples\Visual C++\Version 6\SeriesTextSource" folder still references the old CLSIDs.
Updating them I could build and run the project without errors in Visual Studio 2010 here, both in 32 and 64bit, in a Windows 8.1 64bit machine.

Find here the corrected project:
http://goo.gl/7Ro3OS

Also check you have both the 32bit and the 64bit versions of the .ocx registered. To register them, open an **elevated command prompt at the TeeChart installation path** and run:

```
regsvr32 "TeeChart2014.ocx"
regsvr32 "64bit files\TeeChart201464.ocx"
```

Comment: I have build the code from the path Specified in X64 bit using visual studio 2012 and executed on windows 8. It still gives me access violation when I click on waterfall button. Also the observation is Tee Editior tool is disabled on windows 8 where as the same is enable if I execute it on windows 7. ON the other hand If I build the code in 32 bit it works fine and Tee Editior   is also shown in enabled mode.

Comment: If you still find problems with it, please arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: After making the necessary Changes now I am able to plot the chart in our application. But still when I try to open Editor Page I am not able to do the same CTeeEditor.Please try the sample code which you have provided and check how whether it works for you.

Comment: Just sent a test ocx that seems to fix the AV when opening and closing the editor in the SeriesTextSource example above.